# Handle file download request in JSF 2.1 + PrimeFaces 5.1

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a web application in JSF 2.1 + PrimeFaces 5.1 that has a datatable where I list records from a database. Each row can be expanded to show some details, and there I have a button to download a XML file that has its contents saved in the DB.

```
<p:dataTable id="event_queue_table_id" var="event" value="#{eventQueueBean.eventQueue}" rowKey="#{event.id}">
...

<p:rowExpansion>
...
 <p:commandButton ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" actionListener="#{eventQueueBean.downloadXml(event.id)}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{fileBean.file}"/>
 </p:commandButton>
</p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

I want to fetch the XML contents from the DB, create the file and prompt the user to open/save it. The bean that controls this datatable looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EventQueueBean implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{fileBean}")
private FileBean fileBean;

public void downloadXml(BigDecimal eventId) {
        try {
            logger.entry(eventId);
            DtoGetXmlEvent dtoGetXmlEvent = null;
            if (eventId != null) {
                dtoGetXmlEvent = eventQueueService.getXmlEvent(eventId);
                String xml = dtoGetXmlEvent.getXml();
                if (xml == null) {
                    // show error message stating that file does not exist
                } else {
                    this.fileBean.download(xml, eventId + ".xml", "application/xml");
                }
            }
            logger.exit();
        } catch (...)
        }
    }
}
```

And my `FileBean` is:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger =  LogManager.getLogger(FileBean.class);

    private StreamedContent file;

    public FileBean() {     
        logger.entry();
    }

    public void download(String content, String fileName, String contentType) {
        logger.entry(fileName, contentType);
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, contentType, fileName);
        logger.exit();
    }

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(StreamedContent file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
```

When I try to download an empty XML (the DB retrieves NULL content), the open/save file prompt does not show, but if I try to refresh the page I get the "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.". How can I avoid this?

Comment: I believe PF version >=4 should use JSF version >= 2.2. Also, I would not use the actionListener on the p:commandButton. I would rather make all the logic to fetch the data and assemble the xml StreamedContent file in a method, like: <p:fileDownload value="#{fileBean.getMyXmlFile(event.id)}"/>

Comment: `<p:fileDownload>` may be working that way - instead of completing the response using `FacesContext#responseComplete();`, when the file contents is empty, it should be trying to perform its full default navigation and rendering the response after the action(Listener) method completes. Thus, it is just like that when you send a synchronous HTTP POST request. To avoid this, check to see, if the file contents is empty. Perform a redirect (to either the same or another page which you like the most ) on your own, when the file contents is empty using `ExternalContext#redirect("/path/to/redirect");`

Comment: I ended up allowing the download of an empty XML file. I just had to avoid passing null content to the ByteArrayInputStream constructor by doing ``InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content != null ? content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : new byte[0]);``